# How can I get Dockerhub to rebuild my images daily?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

We have our base images set up on Dockerhub, and they will rebuild whenever the upstream repositories change.

In our Dockerfiles we install several packages with apt-get.
We'd like to have the most recent versions of these packages at all times. Since these packages have nothing to do with the upstream repo's, we'd need to reinstall them into our base image regularly.

One seemingly simple solution would be to have a scheduled rebuild of our images, for example daily or hourly. Each run would pull in the latest versions and bake it into the base image.

However, I can't find any way to do this. There's no option for it in the Dockerhub UI, and I can't find any reference for an API call or webhook that I can trigger from a cron job.

Has anyone come across a way to set up scheduled builds, or a reason why something this (seemingly) straightforward is unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `Build triggers (Trigger your Automated Build by sending a POST to a specific endpoint.` in `Configure Automated Builds`. Unfortunately, this feature was changed recently and I'm not able to find current documentation. There was option to POST some data, e.g. `'docker_tag=dev'` to trigger specific build by docker tag/branch/...

Comment: You're absolutely right! Builds > Configure Automated Builds > At the bottom.  You can create a webhook to POST to, and it will trigger all configured builds. Just tried it and it works flawlessly.
No idea if they just added that or if I completely missed it. But either way: thank you!